# How find every thing but not one word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In text i want to find structures like every thing till some text, but not match between some word.

Example in text:

```
Templates : You can add custom templates for your theme. Updated on 2010 look[124] end
Media RSS feed : Add the Cooliris Effect to your gallery Updated on 2011 look[124]
Role settings : Each gallery has a author Updated at 2010 ...  look[124] end
AJAX based thumbnail generator : No more server Updated on 2010 look[124] end limitation during the batch process Copy/Move : Copy or move images between Updated on 2010 this look[124] galleries Sortable Albums : Create your own sets of images Updated on 2010 this look[124] end
Upload or pictures via a zip-file (Not in Safe-mode)
Watermark function : You can add a watermark image or text 
...
```

I need to find "Updated .*[124] **end**" every match must start this "Update" and ends with "[number]" and word "**end**". But some text looks very similar, but **not** ends with word "**end**". This text must **not mach**. How to make it work?

I try to write

```
/Updated(.*?)\[.*?\]\send/msi
```

or

```
Updated(.*?)\[.*?\](?!Updated)\send
```

But this takes strings like:

```
Updated on 2011 look[124] Role settings : Each gallery has a author Updated at 2010 ...  look[124] end
Updated on 2010 this look[124] galleries Sortable Albums : Create your own sets of images Updated on 2010 this look[124] end
```

How to write regex witch skips bad matches?

http://regexr.com?2vh1j

Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: And, bear in mind that regexen are greedy, they'll try to match the longest thing on a line they can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying for with your second regex:

```
Updated\s++(?>(?!Updated\b|end\b)\S+\s+)*+end\b
```

In other words, match `Updated` and look for the corresponding `end`.  If you find another `Updated` first, you know you started at the wrong place, so abandon that match.  I excluded `end` as well because that lets me match the words possessively (i.e., with `*+`); the regex never has to backtrack to find or (more importantly) eliminate a match.

If you really have to specify the `look[nnn]` part, this should do the trick:

```
Updated\s++(?>(?!Updated\b|end\b|look\[\d+\])\S+\s+)*+look\[\d+\]\s+end\b
```

Add the `i` flag for a case-insensitive match if you need to, but you don't need the `m` or `s` flags.  If this seems overly complicated, it's because I don't know your data as well as you do.  There's a good chance this is all you really need:

```
Updated(?:(?!Updated).)*\send
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the invalid matches have a `[124]`, but not an `end`, you can filter those out by  not allowing a `[` between `Updated` and the end sequence, like this:

```
Updated([^[]*?)\[\d*\]\send
```

Answer (score 1):

To match a string that does not contain `Updated` you can use constructs like:

```
(?:[^U]+|U(?!pdated))*
```

and

```
(?:(?!Updated).)*
```

Using the first alternative would give you an expression like:

```
Updated((?:[^U]+|U(?!pdated))*)\[\d+\]\send
```

---

First alternative explained:

```
(?:          # non-capturing group
[^U]+        # any characters that aren't "U"
|U(?!pdated) # or a "U" which is not followed bu "pdated" (ie. not "Updated")
)*           # repeated as much as possible
```

Second alternative:

```
(?:          # non-capturing group
(?!Updated). # Use a lookahead check at every character to make sure it's not "Updated"
)*           # repeated as much as possible
```

Comment: +1, and I'd definitely go with the second approach.  The first one might be faster, but not by much.  Not enough to justify the readability hit, anyway.  See my answer for the performance fetishists' approach. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy regexp

```
Updated.*?\[.*?\]( end)?
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
Updated([^[]*)\[124\]\s+end
```

Explanation:

```
Updated          # Word 'updated'
[^[]*            # All chars until '['
\[124\]          # String '[124]'
\s+              # One or more spaces.
end              # String 'end'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a different approach:

```
/Updated[\w.\s]*\[\d+\]\send/
```

**Explanation:**

```
Updated
```

This will match the word `Updated`

```
[\w\d.\s]*
```

then all letters, numbers, spaces and dots (u can add any characters u wish)

```
\[\d+\]
```

then a number between brackets

```
\send
```

than a space and finally the word end

Comment: I think instead of `(\w*\d*\.*\s*)*` you meant `[\w.\s]*`.